# Can the = operator be overloaded for a private record type with generic members?

Tags: generics, operator-overloading, ada

I'm trying to overload the equality operator for a generic linked list class. Here's the relevant code:

### list.ads:

```
generic
    type Element_Value_Type is private;

package List is
    type List_Type   is private;
    type Element     is private;
    type Element_Ptr is private;

    function "=" (L, R : List_Type) return Boolean;

    --  Other linked list function declarations  --

private
    type Element is
        record
            Value : Element_Value_Type;
            Next  : Element_Ptr;
            Prev  : Element_Ptr;
        end record;

    type Element_Ptr is access Element;

    type List_Type is
        record
            Length : Integer     := 0;
            Head   : Element_Ptr := null;
            Tail   : Element_Ptr := null;
        end record;
end List;
```

---

### list.adb:

```
package body List is
    function "=" (Left, Right : List_Type) return Boolean is
    begin
        --  Code for equality checking  --
    end "=";

    --  Other function implementations  --
end List;
```

---

### main.adb:

```
with Text_IO;
with List;
use Ada;

procedure Main is
    package Int_Lists is new List (Integer);

    procedure Print_List (List : Int_Lists.List_Type) is
    begin
        --  code to print the contents of a list  --
    end

    L1, L2 : Int_Lists.List_Type;
begin
    Int_Lists.Append (L1, 1);
    Int_Lists.Append (L2, 1);
    Int_Lists.Append (L1, 2);
    Int_Lists.Append (L2, 2);

    Text_IO.Put_Line (Item => Boolean'Image (L1 = L2));
end Main;
```

---

And this is the error that I get in the last line of the body of Main:

```
operator for private type "List_Type" defined at list.ads:X, instance at line X is not directly visible
```

Is there any way to get it to see the "=" function? It works if I do `Int_Lists."=" (L1, L2)`, or if I put `use Int_Lists` before the body of Main, but the first one sort of defeats the purpose of operator overloading and the second one allows unqualified access to all of the List functions from within Main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use "=" with a private type generic parameter, however I would advise passing in the "=" function along with the private type but defaulting to the visible one, as the `with function … is <>` indicates.

**Also**, note that when comparing `Element` you have to compare the value, not the entire record. (See the definition of "=" with Element parameters; it's in the private section as one of Ada 2012's expression functions.)

`Test_List.ads`

```
generic
    type Element_Value_Type is private;
    with function "=" (Left, Right : Element_Value_Type) Return Boolean is <>;
    -- Image only for debugging.
    with function Image( Value : Element_Value_Type ) Return String;
package Test_List is
    type List_Type   is private;
    type Element     is private;
    type Element_Ptr is private;

    function "=" (L, R : List_Type) return Boolean;
    Procedure Append(List : in out List_Type; Item : Element_Value_Type);
    function Image( List : List_Type ) Return String;

private
    type Element is
        record
            Value : Element_Value_Type;
            Next  : Element_Ptr;
            Prev  : Element_Ptr;
        end record;

    function "=" (Left, Right : Element ) Return boolean is
    ( Left.Value = Right.Value );


    type Element_Ptr is access Element;

    type List_Type is
        record
            Length : Integer     := 0;
            Head   : Element_Ptr := null;
            Tail   : Element_Ptr := null;
        end record;
end Test_List;
```

`Test_List.adb`

```
Package Body Test_List is

    function "=" (L, R : List_Type) return Boolean is
    begin
    Return Result : Boolean:= L.Length = R.Length do
        -- We only need to check if lengths are equal.
        if not Result then Return; end if;

        declare
        SubType NN_Element_Ptr is Not Null Element_Ptr;
        L_Cursor : NN_Element_Ptr:= L.Head;
        R_Cursor : NN_Element_Ptr:= R.Head;
        begin
        loop
            if L_Cursor.Value /= R_Cursor.Value then
            Result:= False;
            Return;
            end if;

            Exit when L_Cursor = L.Tail;
            L_Cursor:= L_Cursor.Next;
            R_Cursor:= R_Cursor.Next;
        end loop;
        end;
    exception
        when Constraint_Error =>
        -- Handle empty lists.
        Result:= L.Tail = R.Tail;
    End return;
    end "=";

    Procedure Append(List : in out List_Type; Item : Element_Value_Type) is
    begin
    List.Tail:= new Element'(
            Value => Item,
            Next  => null,
            Prev  => List.Tail
             );
    -- If this is the inital element we link head to ie, if not we need
    -- to link the previous tail's next-pointer to the current tail.
    if List.Length = 0 then
        List.Head := List.Tail;
    else
        List.Tail.Prev.Next:= List.Tail;
    end if;
    List.Length:= List.Length + 1;
    end Append;

    Function Image( List : List_Type ) Return String is
    Separator : Constant String := ", ";

    Function Image( Item : Element_Ptr ) Return String is
    begin
        if Item = Null then
        Return "";
        else
        Return Image(Item.Value) & Separator & Image(Item.Next);
        end if;
    end Image;

    Temp : String:= Image( List.Head );
    begin
    Return '(' & Temp(temp'First..temp'Last-Separator'Length) & ')';
    end Image;

End Test_List;
```

`test.adb`

```
With
Test_List,
Ada.Text_IO;

Procedure Test is
    Package J is new Test_List( Integer, Image => Integer'Image );
    L1, L2 : J.List_Type;
    Use J;

Begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( Image(L1) );
    J.Append (L1, 1);
    J.Append (L2, 1);
    J.Append (L1, 2);
    J.Append (L2, 2);
    J.Append (L1, 3);
    J.Append (L2, 3);
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( Image(L1) );
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( "List equality: " & Boolean'(L1 = L2)'Img );
    J.Append (L2, 1);
    J.Append (L1, 2);    
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line( "List equality: " & Boolean'(L1 = L2)'Img );
End Test;
```

Output is:

```
()
( 1,  2,  3)
List equality: TRUE
List equality: FALSE
```

Comment: Just tried it (with the first code block in the .ads file and the second in the .adb), and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Ok, let me fire up the compiler and see what I can do.

Comment: Note `Use J`... you could also `Use type J.List_Type`.

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to avoid a ```use``` statement since the "=" function will still have to be qualified if more than one instantiation of the Test_List package exists in a procedure. After looking more into it, though, I think I might be asking for too much magic out of the compiler.

Comment: **sigh** Let me ask explicitly... did you try `use type`?
Because it works perfectly after I prefix the calls to Image [in the example] with `J`.

Comment: Nope, I missed reading your comment somehow. Thanks for the help and sorry for the apparent frustration I caused!

Comment: Don't worry about it; we all sometimes get blinded by what we're _trying_ to say that we can't say it well. (Same with hearing.)

Answer (score 3):

In `Main`, after

```
package Int_Lists is new List (Integer);
```

you can either write

```
use type Int_Lists.List_Type;
```

or

```
function "=" (L, R : Int_Lists.List_Type) return Boolean
  renames Int_Lists."=";
```

Personally, I'd go for `use type`. This is what it's for.